# How to capture custom variables in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So as a conversion takes place on site.com (tracked by Google Analytics), a user ID is generated within a javascript on the page but is not captured anywhere but this JS call.  How can one associate the user ID (within that script) with the conversion that takes place utilizing Google Analytics and custom variables?

Thanks

Comment: [Custom Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) might be helpful with what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I'm inclined to suggest using Goals rather than Custom Variables.

Goals can be easily configured in Google Analytics Admin section as below:

[image: Goals screenshot]

You can either configure a **page destination or an event** as the trigger. An event can be easily configured as the following:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'UserID', 'Generation', 'optional string']);">Generate</a>
```

---

You can achieve the same by setting custom variables like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'UserID',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
      userID,               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

The difference being that custom variable will form part of segmention data. On the other hand, Goals will be displayed in their own reporting section, under **Conversion**.

I'll leave a link for further reading: [20 Ways to Use Google Analytics Custom Variables](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/08/28/20-ways-use-custom-variables/).

Comment: How would you suggest utilizing goals to capture this user ID?  Even further, how would it be done within GTM?

Comment: I've amended the answer to better explain Goals. Nevertheless, they are not used to capture data, you would still use custom variables for that. As for Tag Manager I haven't had the pleasure to work with it yet, but I'm sure the integration won't be that hard.